Excel: Create PivotTable using Comma-Delimited Values & Add Custom Filter
I have a file where I need to completly transform the data into something usable for my team. This was a request from my boss.
I have data like this:



Feature ID
Impacted Device
Decision




Wi-Fi
2018_iPhone10, 2021_iPhone11, 2022_iPhone12
Keep


Bluetooth
2019_iPhone11, 2020_iPhone12, 2021_iPhone13
Keep


ActnBtn
2023_iPhone15, 2024_iPhone16
Drop



That needs to look like this, in a PivotTable preferably:
FILTER BY: iPhone (iPhone10, iPhone11, iPhone12, etc)



Feature ID
2018

2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024




Wi-Fi
Keep

Keep
Keep
Keep
Keep
Keep
Keep


Bluetooth
Keep

Keep
Keep
Keep
Keep
Keep
Keep


ActnBtn
--

--
--
--
--
Drop
Drop



I've tried PowerQuery editor, but I am a complete novice and never used it before. I have been told it is the best thing to use for my query...

Load your data from Excel to PowerQuery and normalize, you can just record your steps while doing it, for example:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Feature ID", type text}, {"Impacted Device", type text}, {"Decision", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Impacted Device", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Impacted Device"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Impacted Device", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Impacted Device", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Impacted Device.1", "Impacted Device.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Impacted Device.1", Int64.Type}, {"Impacted Device.2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"Impacted Device.1", "Year"}, {"Impacted Device.2", "Impacted device"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"


Load the new table back to Excel making sure that the "Add this data to the Data Model" option is checked:

In the "Power Pivot" tab create a new measure:
=CONCATENATEX(Table1,Table1[Decision],",")

Now you can create a new pivot table using the Data Model as its source:

